# Use a IDBConnection in a service

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dapper

On an MVC project I have a service layer with commands and queries.

In some of these commands and queries I use Dapper which needs a Connection.

```
public class GetPostsStatsQuery {

  public GetPostsStatsQuery() {
  }

  public PostStats Execute() {
     // Code here
  }
}
```

What options do I have to create a connection and use it in dapper query?

1. Can I inject one? How and with which lifecycle?
2. Should I use "using (..."?
3. Any other option?

Comment: there are some solutions how to create one connection per request, but i think it's better to open new connection within each query or command. Don't worry about performance, there is a connection pool which cares about connection reusing.

Answer (score 0):

Any of those options is fine, as is *just about any other option* (for example, a connection-factory). This is entirely an implementation detail, and should be driven by your other requirements.  There is no single "right answer" here.